# UIMenuController not showing when UICollectionViewCell's subView has userInteraction Enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uimenucontroller

Basically I have an imageView inside cell whose `isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to `true` as it has a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Now the problem is when I long press the cell outside the imageView area it shows the menu but when I long the imageView itself the menu isn't shown. I didn't understand the behaviour.

I also noticed that even if I remove `UITapGestureRecognizer`, it still doesn't work. So it has something to do with `isUserInteractionEnabled` property.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the user interaction on the image view, because it blocks the interaction on the cell.

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: It has a tap gesture can't disable it.

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: On tap simple open the `imageView` and on long press `UICollectionView` delegate methods gets called and menuController is visible.